# Selenium: Automation JQGrid Speed test

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, jqgrid, automation

Is there any way to add speed test in selenium to test my jqgrid table.

I am doing is test an automation on a jqgrid table and checking whether content is displayed within specific time for instance. Grid should load in less than 1 sec.

Till now I am just automating to to load first page, last page, next and previous and display no. of pages. Now next step is to check the time it takes to load. Is there any possibility to do that?

**Update**

I am using nunit to run my automation.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend a little on how you would define the time of loading. Do you want to take in consideration the time for *processing the server response* or only the time of *building grid DOM*.

jqGrid set `totaltime` parameter, which is the time in milliseconds for processing the server response and the building grid DOM by web browser. You can use `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "totaltime")` to get the value. If you need to take in consideration the time for Ajax request then you can use remember `new Date()` inside of `loadBeforeSend` callback inside of your custom variable (`startTime` for example) and then use `new Date() - startTime` at the end of `loadComplete` callback.

Comment: No you didn't get. First of all, I am creating a automated test I am not creating a new JQgrid and its load time. I am testing already existed JQGrid on my site. Now, I have to test that its should only take less than 1 sec to load the table. If not test failed.

Comment: Let say I have this [table](http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/loading_data/million_sql/default.aspx). I am creating an automation test to check the loading time

Comment: @user120: You can open the page with the table, and to type on console `
$("#JQGrid2").jqGrid("getGridParam", "totaltime")`. I did it and could see values like 12 or 14 on Google Chrome and 22 on IE11. It's the time in ms to load the table, without the time of pure Ajax request.

Comment: @user120: Sorry, but it seems we speak about different things. If you want to get the information about loading time of jqGrid you have to white small JavaScript code which get the information. I don't use Selenium or nunit myself. Thus if you have to solve the problem that you have to use write small JavaScript code.

Comment: I knew you didn't understood and I am trying to find a solution. If you have any solution please do share so that I will be able to understand and learn. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user120: I repeat that I don't know Selenium. If you can you **execute some JavaScript code from Selenium** then I can try to help you.